# How does sp_send_dbmail convert the query into text in the email body

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add a "signature" at the bottom of a stored procedure to show what job ran it, what server it was run on, and the stored procedure name (I have the code figured out). But if I try to insert the signature, it is placed above the query result in the email. I was trying to capture that text result to manually add it to the email body so I can place the signature underneath it.

How does SQL Server convert a query into the text displayed in an email using `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`?

Furthermore, is there a way I can capture that text into a local variable?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What would you like to know? In particular "How does SQL Server convert.." apparently by executing the stored procedure code. What additional details would you like to know? A good place to start would be [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: Also why do you need to get query results in the text form in a local variable? For most practical reason table variable and the actual query results are better and for the rest see this [workaround](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/)

Comment: I'm trying to add a "signature" at the bottom of a stored procedure to show what job ran it, what server it was run on, and the stored procedure name (I have the code figured out). But if I try to insert the signature, it is placed above the query result in the email. I was trying to capture that text result to manually add it to the email body so I can place the signature underneath it. Any other details I can easily provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure, you can see what it's doing.  The short version is that it

- runs the query and stores the results in a system table (sysmail_mailitems), along with all the other message details
- sends the message to the mail queue
- an external mail service actually constructs and sends the message to the recipients

The point is that there is no easy way to customize how the email message is assembled.  You'll be better off designing some sort of external process of your own to construct and send the email.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the past I have build out the email as HTML, and injected the query results into the message body variable (rather than using the @query param) - this required, or at least i used, some "FOR XML PATH" functionality to build out an html table within the body.

Forgive the terribleness, I don't have dbmail set up at home so i can't give this a test with the actual sp, but it should get the point across - and yes it's kind of messy, but it DOES work :P

```
declare @body varchar(max)

set @body = 'Hello world<br /><br />'

declare @temp table (
    id int primary key identity(1,1) ,
    name varchar(50) ,
    isAwesome bit default 0
)

insert into @temp (name, isAwesome)
select 'turtle', 1
union all select 'popsicles', 0
union all select 'bees', 0

declare @xml xml = (
    select  name as td, isAwesome as td
    from    @temp
    for     xml raw ('tr'), elements
)

set @body = @body + '<table>'
set @body = @body + convert(varchar(max), @xml)
set @body = @body + '</table>'

set @body = @body +  '
<br /><br />
Signature'

select @body
```

Comment: I've used HTML formatting before and it makes a really nice and clean table, but I was just hoping for a few lines of code to stick at the end of a procedure. I appreciate your response though!